# Cell not displaying text immediately when using AspectGetter

Tags: c#, winforms, objectlistview

I have a list of object which I'm using to populate an `ObjectListView`. The listview has a couple of columns that are not bound to the model, but instead I use `AspectGetter` as follows:

```
olvColumn1.AspectGetter = delegate (object row)
{
    var item = ((MyItem)row).OtherClass;

    return string.Format("{0} {1}", item.Property1, item.Property2);
};
```

The above works fine when I add new items to the list.

However, when I set the list's `DataSource` to a `BindingSource` (which in turn is bound to my model), the columns where I'm using `AspectGetter` are not showing their text immediately.

When I hover over the rows, the text will appear.

I've tried forcing the list to refresh its items by calling `BuildList` and `RefreshObjects` but it didn't work.

Is there a way to actually force the list to refresh its items so that all columns are displayed correctly immediately?

**EDIT**

As suggested, I tried the following but it still doesn't work

```
foreach (var item in model.Items)
{
    olvList.UpdateObject(item); //Also tried RefreshObject
}
```

Comment: Have you tried calling UpdateObjects()? Alternatively you could implement INotifyPropertyChanged.

Comment: @Rev1.0 UpdateObjects() doesn't work either. I'm reluctant to use INotifyPropertyChanged as the model is a DTO class.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe you are not just changing the model properties but replacing a model from the data source completely? The OLV compares objects by reference. If you query a new object from a database for example and replace an existing object (that is know by the OLV) from the data source, calling RefreshObject(newObject) obviously won't work.

Comment: @Rev1.0 This might be the problem because the model is ICollection<T> whilst, to call UpdateObjects or RefreshObjects I need to call ToList() on the model.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed a pitfall. I faced that same problem once where I was fetching/updating single model objects from time to time. I think I ended up removing the outdated model from the list and reinserting the new one at that index. I though about implementing an IComparer (or whatever the interface was called) for the models, I think the OLV would then be able to compare the models by UID for example. But if you can't touch your model it doesn't help you.